# Additional column in customer address grid in Admin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address, customer-grid

I have added one customer address custom attribute. it is showing in customer address form i want to show that as coulum in customer address grid in admin with value.

i have added this code:

```
 <column name="addressval"  sortOrder="95">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">addressval</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Column is added but the value is not showing in this. how to get the value which was set in form?

Answer (score 2):

`options` node is missed , which is essential to show the values

`<options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Address\Attribute\Source\CustomAttribute"/>`

Add a source Model class which returns the values of your customer address attribute and use the source model class in `options` node like this

```
<column name="addressval" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="95">
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Customer\Address\Attribute\Source\CustomAttribute"/>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">addressval</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

Comment: I tried this.... but still not getting value on that field

Comment: then most likely its because of your source model class...check whether it returns the option values for your select column.

Comment: just one question, what should I write in that custom attribute file. can you give me some code examples?

Comment: i am getting this error: [2021-02-22 09:47:38] report.CRITICAL: Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /var/www/html/xxx-anchor/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php on line 60 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /var/www/html/xxx-anchor/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php on line 60 at /var/www/html/xxx-anchor/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []